# How to update ALL detail grids columnDef in AG Grid master detail view?

Tags: javascript, angular, ag-grid

I have the latest enterprise edition of Ag-Grid in the Angular app.
I've server-side data rendered in Ag-Gird master detail view.
Also, I've implemented the save table state for both master & detail grids but the issue is, that when I hide some columns from the detail grid of one row, it does not update the detail grid for other rows. How can I update that to reflect on every detail grid?

[image: problem-illustration]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've achieved it using the `gridReady` option of the detail grid:

```
onGridReady: e => {
        const state = this.paymentsColApi?.getColumnState();
        if (state) {
          e.columnApi.applyColumnState({
            state: state,
            applyOrder: true
          });
        }
        this.paymentsGridApi = e.api;
        this.paymentsColApi = e.columnApi;
        if (this.isFirstTimePaymentsGridLoad) {
          this.restorePaymentsGrid();
        }
      }
```